# Snap SVG: Suspending an event listener during the course of an animation

Tags: javascript, snap.svg

I'm trying to suspend the event listener of this animation I made such that the 
click event won't trigger another animation until the previous one is completed. I tried using booleans (as in the example) but I don't understand why it won't work.

Note: Can't use jquery.

Example: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6r6ty6o6/4/)

```
var speed = 250,
suspend = true;

[].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.arrow_button' ) ).forEach( function( el ) {

    var s = Snap( el.querySelector( 'svg' ) ),
        path = s.select( 'path' ),
        returnPath = path.attr('d'),
        route = el.getAttribute( 'data-path-route' ),
        callback = function () {
            path.animate( { 'path' : returnPath }, speed, mina.easeout );
            suspend = true;
        };

    el.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
        if( suspend ) {
            suspend = false;
            path.animate( { 'path' : route }, speed, mina.easein, callback );
        };
    } );

} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you set `suspend` to true right away in your callback-function. You could set a timeout inside the callback-function, and set `suspend` to true after around 250ms (the length/speed of the animation). [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6r6ty6o6/6/)

```
var speed = 250,
suspend = true;

[].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.arrow_button' ) ).forEach( function( el ) {

    var s = Snap( el.querySelector( 'svg' ) ),
        path = s.select( 'path' ),
        returnPath = path.attr('d'),
        route = el.getAttribute( 'data-path-route' ),
        callback = function () {
            path.animate( { 'path' : returnPath }, speed, mina.easeout );
            setTimeout(function(){
                 suspend = true;      
            },speed)
        };

    el.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
        if( suspend ) {
            suspend = false;
            path.animate( { 'path' : route }, speed, mina.easein, callback );
        };
    } );

} );
```

EDIT: after having a closer look at snapsvg.io's documentation,
I figured a better way of handling the situation you are facing. Instead of using a timeout, you can add a callback function in your easeout-animation like this [updated plunkr](https://jsfiddle.net/6r6ty6o6/7/):

```
var speed = 250,
    suspend = true;
[].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.arrow_button' ) ).forEach( function( el ) {
    var s = Snap( el.querySelector( 'svg' ) ),
        path = s.select( 'path' ),
        returnPath = path.attr('d'),
        route = el.getAttribute( 'data-path-route' ),
        callback = function () {
            path.animate( { 'path' : returnPath }, speed, mina.easeout, function(){
               suspend=true;
            });
        };
    el.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
  console.log("test",suspend);
        if( suspend ) {
            suspend = false;
            path.animate( { 'path' : route }, speed, mina.easein, callback );
        };
    } );
} );
```

This callback function will be called when the animation ends, making it unnecessary to set your own timeout. From the [snapsvg.io docs](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.animate)